# Creating a new XML File with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

is it possible to create a new XML File in a Javascript Function, and filling it up with data?

Comment: Possibly but depends on what environment (browser/server) and what you mean exactly by *"create file"*.

Comment: I meant with create file that my aim is to create a new XML document with data, which i get from a Javascript Function, where i can dynamically choose data on a main HTML page and when everything is finished it should run on a server.

Comment: Since can only write to file on server using server side programming language.... probably easier to send data there and build the xml there. You can also build the xml as string in browser ... but still have to send that string to server and write it to file there

Comment: Also if not critical what file type would choose json over xml for simplicity

Comment: Oh ok, but  I should use xml because i need as result a xml document